# Jasminerice and stylesheets for fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have found [jasminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) very helpful for getting all my Jasmine tests to run via Rails 3.1's asset pipeline. The only thing I remain stuck with, is that I cannot get my setup to load any stylesheets (that go with my fixtures) and I need them for a couple of dom / element-style specific tests. Does anybody know how to get the stylesheets to be loaded in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the Jasminerice gem and bradphelan (the Jasminerice author) has pulled that change into the source on Github. So in order to use use stylesheets in your Jasmine tests running through Jasminerice, simply refer to the gem on Github in your `Gemfile` like so: `gem "jasminerice", :git => 'git://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice.git'`. The documentation has also been updated on Github.

Answer (score 2):

Support for CSS files has been added recently, the [README](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) states:

For including stylesheets in your specs, jasminerice uses a spec.css file. Create such a file next to the spec.js.coffee file:

```
spec/javascripts/spec.css
```

and in that file, use sprockets directives to include the right css files, e.g.

```
/*
*= require application
*/
```

The change is fairly new so you may want to include the gem directly from the latest github version:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'jasminerice', git: 'git://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice.git'
```

You may also want to be precise with your css markup, so as to not mess up Jasmine's spec runner page as [the css files (as the js files) are included directly into it](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice/commit/4c1c232a0d98621c8b845c5ae921be942845aba3).

Comment: Never mind, :-) thanks for the commit anyway! I'll leave the answer as it may help others who didn't know about it.

Comment: Thanks Olivier. I did actually write this myself, but I posted it as answer to a wrong question. DUH! That's probably what you get when you code to long at night. ;)
Just to be complete I'll post that answer again here (and up yours for the effort you took)